# Proxy all console outputs [logs, error, warning, etc] into HTML

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, smart-tv

I'm looking for a solution for print the equivalent of what I see in the console into a div element in the HTML.
I'm developing with Web technologies into a TV so no Browser tools provided.
I've found out this solution:

```
(function () {
    if (!console) {
        console = {};
    }
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += 'LOG: ' + (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += 'LOG: ' + message + '<br />';
        }
    }
    console.error = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += 'ERROR: ' + (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += 'ERROR: ' + message + '<br />';
        }
    }
    console.warn = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += 'WARN: ' + (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += 'WARN: ' + message + '<br />';
        }
    }
})();
```

but I need a more robust solution that print out all the content of the console, not only what passes trought this three functions.
Is that possible via ES5 JavaScript?

Comment: If you override the `window.console.whatevermethod` that should affect everything, provided they don't capture those methods inside an IIFE

Comment: @Taplar I've tested this solution and it works but not all the information's present in the console's output are logs, warns or errors and are provided by the Javascript. Sometimes the browser itself logs information or in general console object has several methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash function  `_.functions` and wrap all console.methods

```
_.functions(console).forEach(function (methodName) {
var oldMethodName = console[methodName];
console[methodName] = function (message) {
    if (typeof message == 'object') {
        logger.innerHTML += methodName + ' : ' + (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
    } else {
        logger.innerHTML += methodName + ' : ' + message + '<br />';
    }
    return oldMethodName.call(console, arguments)
}
})
```

I would also suggest to add `onError` listener to the window and redefine `setTimeout` to get errors from it.

Comment: Did You find https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy?

Comment: Proxy is a good thing. but it does not work on most on smart-tvs

Comment: can You demonstrate it with compatibility tables MDN like?

Comment: no. just remember that netcast(old lg from 2011-2014) and orsai (old samsung) does not support them. But there is a proxy polyfill that you can import and use